# Powershell ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the OWNER of a process, code :

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'}).getowner() | Foreach-Object user | out-string**
```

This works great under win8 but in win7 I get this msg :

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "user" val
ue of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent GP\scripts\9660.ps1:1 char:
108
+ (Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'
}).getowner() | Foreach-Object <<<<  user | out-string
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], Parameter 
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerSh 
   ell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Help please! Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `foreach-object user`, use `select -expand user`. This is equivalent to doing `foreach-object { $_.user }` which is probably what you meant to do. Improvements to flexibility in the grammar allow your first attempt in later versions of powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The older version of Powershell won't work with the simplified syntax.  This should work on either one:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | 
 where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'}).getowner() |
 Foreach-Object { $_.user | out-string }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'}).getowner() | select user
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but in my case, there was a non-printable character in my script that appeared after one of the }'s.  ASCII code 03.  I found that by opening the script in a binary editor (Textpad8).  I deleted this character and it fixed the problem for me.